# Excel if statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have this simple if statement in an Excel spreadsheet and I would like to know the proper way to leave a cell blank when the cell a column "V" has no date or is a blank cell.

`=IF(V11>K11, "LATE","On-Time")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

`=IF(AND(LEN(V11)>0,OR(CELL("format",V11)={"D1","D2","D3","D4","D5"})),IF(V11>K11, "LATE","On-Time"),"not a valid date")`

Comment: so if V11 is > K11 by 30 days how would I get the cell to-be red??

Answer (score 0):

Blank cell = 0 in Excel, is this what you want?

```
=IF(V11=0, 0, "cell in V column is not blank")
```